# Sencha Touch 2 - Add model to store only once

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a store which gets its value through a proxy to the server. But I want to hard code one country (null country) which should be appended to the store around in the sencha code

I tried a naive

```
data: [
    {
        id: '999',
        countryCode: 'NullCountry',
        countryName: 'Null (+nothing)',
        countryPhoneCode: null
    }
]
```

But it doesnt work (it was just an attempt). How can I do this?

```
Ext.define('Sencha.store.CountryStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        id : 'CountryStore',
        model:'Sencha.model.user.Country',

        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url : '/countries',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept' : 'application/json'
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'countries'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true,
        data: [
            {
                id: '999',
                countryCode: 'NullCountry',
                countryName: 'Null (+nothing)',
                countryPhoneCode: null
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could listen to the store [load](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-load) event and then add the new record then:

```
Ext.define('Sencha.store.CountryStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        id : 'CountryStore',
        model:'Sencha.model.user.Country',

        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url : '/countries',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept' : 'application/json'
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'countries'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true,

        listeners: {
            load: function(me) {
                me.add({
                    id: '999',
                    countryCode: 'NullCountry',
                    countryName: 'Null (+nothing)',
                    countryPhoneCode: null
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```